# Input value is not passed to child component angular5?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have two components dashboard & skills, and i want to pass the type in dashboard to be used in skill. But getting error undefined.

Dashboard Component:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  type: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.type = "Agent";
  }
```

And the Skill component is:

```
export class SkillComponent implements OnInit{
 @Input() type: string;  
 constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.type);
}
```

Dashboard component template:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <app-skill-list type="type"></app-skill-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It shouldn't be undefined, it would be `'type'`, but if you want to pass `this.type = "Agent"` value to child component use attribute binding `[type]="type"`... **Question** is `SkillComponent` is `app-skill-list` component? if no then respective component have `type` @Input binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use annotation **[type]**

```
<app-skill-list [type]="type"></app-skill-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value of one variable of a component to other component by queryParams.

Use [queryParams] directives along with routerLink to pass queryParams.

```
Dashboard.html
```

`<a [routerLink] = "['/skill']" [queryParams] ="{type :[type] }">`

```
Skill.ts

data :any;
type : any;



Export class Skill implements OnInit {

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)

ngOnInit (){ 


this.data = this.route
                . queryParams
                . subscribe (params =>{
                   this.type = params['type']

                      })
//Now you can console it in skill component
}
}
```